# Registration of the app failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm very new so ... 
I was watching a "how-to" video, followed the instructions (create a "Visual C#", "Store Apps", "Blank App".  Changed the background color to orange, then pressed Ctrl + f5 and below is the error.

```
1>Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. 
Windows cannot deploy to path G:\C#_Stuff\Projects\WindowStoreAppOrange\WindowStoreAppOrange\WindowStoreAppOrange\bin\Debug of file system type FAT32. 
The path must be located on an NTFS volume. (0x80073
```

Any helpful thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message clearly states that your project cannot be deployed to a drive with a `FAT32` filesystem. Move your deploy directory to a `NTFS` drive.

Comment: I've got a similar error but mine says "...of file system type NTFS". What does it want it to be on?

Comment: @GeekyMonkey Try changing the location of the deploy folder to drive C

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but figured it out.  Maybe someone else will be helped with this information.  I'm new to C# and I was following along in a book creating a basic UWP application.  The Build succeeded, but debugging failed.  The error was: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFD] Windows cannot deploy to path AppX of file system type exFAT.

It turns out that the problem was that my source files were located on my external hard drive.  I generally keep all of my source files on my external hard drive.  So, I copied my source file folder to a new folder on my c drive.  Compiled it and executed it.  It worked.  So, it looks like all my development files for C# need to be on my local machine drive.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35477264)